# keeping values returned from grap api request

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

i use the following code to send a request to the graph api and display it in a label

```
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"40123148903?fields=picture" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id<FBGraphObject> result, NSError *error)
         {
             if(!error)
             {
                  self.tryLabal.text = [[[result objectForKey:@"picture"] objectForKey:@"data"]objectForKey:@"url"];

             }
         }
         ];
```

the problem is it only lets me use the graph object inside the block. i want to keep the returned result.

i tried declaring a id property and assigning it the result id

```
self.tryGraphObject = result;
```

but that doesnt seem to work. what am i doing wrong? how can i save the information from the call for later use?

Answer (score 0):

you can use method from facebook delegate such as

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {}

Comment: this is method from FBRequestDelegate.
you can override it and save your data here. after any request - this methods will be invoked if you receive succesfull respons.

Comment: but the response here is just a url, how do i get the object from it? i find it wierd they only let you work on the object inside the block

Answer (score 0):

sorry. my mistake. correct method is
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result

example

request 
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];

response
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
       //ok so it's a dictionary with one element (key="data"), which is an array of dictionaries, each with "name" and "id" keys
    items = [[(NSDictionary *)result objectForKey:@"data"]retain];
    for (int i=0; i<[items count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *friend = [items objectAtIndex:i];
        long long fbid = [[friend objectForKey:@"id"]longLongValue];
        NSString *name = [friend objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"id: %lld - Name: %@", fbid, name);
    }
}

Comment: i dont think this is viable for sdk 3.1. it seems the in the 3.1 version instead of "with delegate" they changed it to that stupid block "with handler".